# How to put a partial differential equation or integrable system in a certain space or manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I'm studying some papers about integrable system. And the problem arises in my mind.

When I search papers, there are many papers such as "Kuramoto model in 3-sphere", "Toda Lattice with hyperelliptic Riemann surface", "... system in torus", "... on closed manifolds" etc.

But in the beginning I learned PDE, we never talk about this PDE in **what space** or in **what sense**.

If it's possible, please tell me the concept.

Comment: This is probably too broad of a question for exchange. It isn't very clear what you are asking. The space on which a PDE is defined is always defined before the PDE (since what is differentiation until you specify the space).

Comment: My main problem is how to or why some papers are set on a torus or a Riemann surface. But you're right, I just need to clarify what the differentiability is.